# jQuery toggle submenu a href is not working

Tags: html, jquery

I have a menu and the link or "a href click" is not working.
jQuery does not give any errors that I am aware of, and the menu opens as desired, but nothing seems to take the user to stackoverflow.com for the link in my code below.    I tried .parent a, but maybe this is not correct.
I made this example based on the example below which is slightly different from the code I posted below.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqjdjjga/16/)

```js
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent a").click(function (e) {
        var elems = $(this).closest('li');
        elems.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
        if (elems.find('.submenu').length) {
            $(".submenu:first", elems).toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.year_2014 .monthly-archive {
    display: none;
}
.january .archive {
    display: none;
}
.february .archive {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent"> <a href="">Hello</a>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>

                </li>
                <li class="parent"> <a href="">Hello</a>

                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li> <a href="">Hello</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="">Hello</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent"> <a href="">Hello</a>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Click</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `$(".parent > a").click(function (e)` in your code?

Answer (score -1):

If I using `$(".parent > a").click(function (e)` can click a link and redirect to link

```js
$(function () {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".parent > a").click(function (e) {
        
        var elems = $(this).closest('li');
        elems.siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
        if (elems.find('.submenu').length) {
            $(".submenu:first", elems).toggle();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent"><a href="">Hello</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"> <a href="">Hello</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li> <a href="">Hello</a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="">Hello</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent"> <a href="">Hello</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li> <a href="">Hello</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Click</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty close to a working solution.  Maybe the code here can help. https://jsfiddle.net/EddyRocket/0nkvm1z9/  And, add this CSS .sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

Comment: To make this extra fancy, use slidetoggle with slow like in this example.  http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/2/  To be honest, I'm not sure why preventdefault is used here, but maybe it is helpful in this case?

Comment: Maybe helpful in this case, bcoz `preventdefault` is a method that is used to prevent default occurrences of a DOM, like `a href` if clicked then the browser page will reload, or a form if we click the submit button it will also reload